# Got upvote, but no reputation, and haven't reached cap yet

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Something strange just happened: I have at this point 160 + 15 reputation, and I got an upvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009475/inheritance-virtual-functions-vs-generic-programming/8009872#8009872) which didn't add any reputation!

Is there an explanation for this? Did the cap get lowered to 160 perhaps?

**Update:** Now, one day later, the tally of yesterday's reputation shows the correct amount (now 200 + 75). Seems like all is well in the long run!

Comment: Huh? There indeed is a non-CW upvote that isn't being counted: http://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb?tab=reputation Strange.

Comment: @Pekka there's actually two not being counted.

Comment: Were any of your answers/questions today deleted? Check the rep audit page to be certain of the rep you have gotten today: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @Oded: Wow, I never know about that audit page! I have no idea how to use it; give me a minute. I don't think any answers got deleted today, but that can't be ruled out.

Comment: If it doesn't change after a rep-recalc, I don't know what this is.

Comment: where exactly are you seeing the 160+15?

Comment: @MarcGravell http://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb?tab=reputation (he's gotten another accept since then, but there's an upvote line near the top with no rep gain)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reputation tab is a bit funny - it doesn't take into account any *deleted* votes on questions/answers, so doesn't quite keep in sync with reality. This means that if you got upvoted on an answer that was later deleted, the value will no longer be visible but still tallied.

To be certain, check the [audit page of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

A reputation recalc should sort it.

Comment: That makes sense - would the question have to be one I answered today? Is there a way of finding out which question? Anyway, that's fine then. Thanks!

Comment: @KerrekSB - Not necessarily. It would have been _deleted_ today. I believe there is no way to find it -finding deleted questions/answer is a feature that has been requested and rejected before.

Answer (score 0):

This discrepancy is now resolved much more quickly in [the new reputation views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), deleted posts now will be reflected on your reputation tab within 5 minutes - almost every other action will appear instantly.